# Spring Webflux Bean Validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I have a simple rest controller (using spring **web-FLUX**), that get a bean to save in database. But as usual, I would like to validate some fields of it before saving.

I have a validation method to be called before save the bean. But how could I do that in a more functional (and appropriate) manner?

I have tried something like:

```
public void save(Mono<MyBean> myBean) {
    myBean.map(this::validateBean).map(myRepository::save)
}
```

But the method *validateBean* is not being called, only when I do something like

```
public void save(Mono<MyBean> myBean) {
    myBean.map(this::validateBean)
          .map(myRepository::save)
          .subscribe();
}
```

I don't know if the **subscribe** part is the most correct one (I believe it isn't), but I think it works because is kind of a terminal operation. Am I right?

Even so, that does not solve my problem, because my validation method throws a *Business*Exception when something is wrong with the bean. And that is exactly what I wanna do.

[EDITED]
This is my rest controller would me something like:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/something")
public Mono<ResponseEntity> salvar(@RequestBody MyBean myBean) {
    return myService.salvar(myBean)
            .map(RestResponses::ok)
            .defaultIfEmpty(RestResponses.empty());
}
```

I know this is not working because my service ir no returning anything. But I do not know what would be the correct way. So I just post an idea. Thanks for understanding...

Could you guys give me some help?

Comment: As far as I know Mono is a "cold" publisher, It means that it should have at least one subsciber to start emmiting data.

Comment: Could you show your actual controller method? Also, the core of this issue is probably the fact that you're relying on blocking methods returning void vs. a reactive repository that should return a `Mono<Void>` when saving the data. Note that subscribing yourself to a Publisher is usually a smell.

Comment: @rvit34, thanks for your comment. Could you please give me some reference about this, so I can understand it better?

Comment: @BrianClozel, Thanks for your comment. I edited my question.

Comment: see https://ordina-jworks.github.io/reactive/2016/12/12/Reactive-Programming-Spring-Reactor.html

Comment: your repository should be reactive as well, with a `Mono<Void> save(MyBean myBean)` signature

Comment: I  also confused about validation when switch to webflux, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48031647/what-is-the-best-way-to-validate-request-in-a-spring-webflux-functional-applicat)